# moving image not working

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

my program wont work. the man is meant to move but I cant even display him properly.
please help me my code is...

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        my_image = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Documents and Settings\\Patrick\\Desktop\\      most commonly used stuff\\game\\bob 1.GIF')
        self.id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=my_image)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.id.pack()
    def left(self, evt):
        print('Left')
        self.x = -2
        canvas.move(self.id, 10, 0)

    def right(self, evt):
        print('Right')
        self.x = 2
        canvas.move(self.id, -10, -0)
    def up(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
        canvas.move(self.id, -0, -10)
    def down(self, evt):
        self.x = 2
        canvas.move(self.id, -0, 10)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos [2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 10



def easy():
    paddle = Paddle(canvas,)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-Right>", paddle.left)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-Left>", paddle.right)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-a>", paddle.right)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-d>", paddle.left)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", paddle.up)
    tk.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", paddle.down)
    b2.destroy()

    while 1:
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)


def start():
    b2.pack()
    b.destroy()

tk = Tk()
tk.title("game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, bg="yellow", width=500, height=400)
canvas.pack()
tk.update
b = Button(tk, text="play", command=start)
b.pack()
b2 = Button(tk, text="easy", command=easy)

console = ['top','bottom','right','left','paddle']
```

I really want this to work and I would really appreciate if somebody would fix it up
thanks to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Nobody is going to debug your code for you. That's your job. Once you find the problematic part of your code and can't seem to fix it yourself, ask a question.

Comment: When you ask questions in the future, please properly indent your code by copy-pasting it directly from your text editor (after testing to see if it runs of course) onto Stack Overflow's text box, highlighting it, and using the {} button.

Comment: @Wooble Ah ok ty, I deleted the comment.

Comment: Caps lock is cruise control for cool. But even on cruise control you have to steer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't be fixed with just a couple of lines. You have a major structural flaw.

For a tkinter program to work, you must call `mainloop`. It's true that you *can* use tkinter without it, but only for very special use cases, and only when you know what you're doing. So the first thing you'll need to do is remove the `while 1` loop completely, and call `mainloop` instead. Do not call `mainloop` from `easy`. Instead, it is usually called as the last line in your program.